# cloud image hangs with blinking cursor when installing gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, virtualization, desktop-environments, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am trying to deploy a VM with ubuntu desktop.

My host is a headless Debian Bookworm with libvirt + qemu as the hypervisor.

I tried the steps below with Jammy and Noble latest cloud images from [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/). I am using the cloud images as it seems the quickest way to deploy a VM. All seems very reproducible.

1. Install the virtual machine with cloud init to create a user.
   user-data is as basic as I could do it to make it work:

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - name: "testuser"
    plain_text_passwd: "testpassword"
    lock-passwd: false
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: sudo
    sudo: "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
```

2. I connect to the VM from my workstation using virt-viewer and virt-manager.
3. Login. All works well!
4. Update the VM

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

5. Reboot
6. Install Gnome Desktop

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

7. Reboot
8. System hangs with a blinking cursor :(

---

What am I missing?
I can use tty2 to login to the terminal and view other things.
`gdm3` is running and enabled
running `xinit` makes tty2 hang with a blinking cursor too.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but don't know what :/

Comment: I don't understand why am I getting downvoted. I genuenly have this problem, yet I am unable to find a solution. If you are downvoting at least write a comment.